# Tag messages on github

Tags: git, tags, github

In [download section on github,](http://github.com/rails/rails/downloads) you can download all version of the project associated with tags. But for some reason the tag descriptions are taken from the last commit.

This happens even if one uses heavy tagging:

```
git tag -a -m "tag commit message"
```

Can I somehow force github to use my tag messages?

Comment: This is the question of what **GitHub web interface** does.  You can report bug on GitHub bugtracker: http://support.github.com/

Comment: No, but you could make a feature request.

Comment: I did make a feature request.

Comment: I guess that means this question can then be closed.

Answer (score 3):

This a [known issue](http://support.github.com/discussions/site/467-tag-downloads-should-derive-description-from-tag-annotation) with GitHub.